# Stop LaTeX compile with a command?

Tags: macros, compiling

Is there a way to stop the compile process through the use of a command? Something like:

```
 \exception{This is a user-set exception.  Compile halted.}
```

So when performing the compile process, the specified text string is displayed to the console, and the compile process aborts?

The reason I want to do something like this is I want to have a conditional statement that checks a user-defined parameter. If the parameter is outside a desired range, I want the user to be informed that they made a bad choice and should change it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solutions below are better, but I just use `\typeout{<text>}\QUIT`, where `\QUIT` is not defined.

Answer (score 40):

```
 \PackageError{mypackage}{you did it wrong}{help text}
```

Comment: And if it is not in a package but in a plain LaTeX file?  For example, i want to produce an error message if my file is compiled with anything other than XeLaTeX.

Comment: `\GenericError` @Alexey

Answer (score 33):

Maybe not the best solution, but for the sake of completeness:

```
\stop
```

in LaTeX and

```
\bye
```

in plain TeX.

Comment: Note: those will produce the output (which might be what you want).

Answer (score 26):

There are a number of error and warning commands for use in different situations. See section 4.9 of [LaTeX2e for class and package authors](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) for details of `\ClassError` and `\PackageError` (also `\ClassWarning` and `PackageWarning`), and have a look at [macros2e.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf) for `\GenericError` (and `\GenericWarning`).

Answer (score 15):

i like @PeterGrill's `\typeout{<text>}\QUIT` approach because after reading the message, the user can choose to hit the enter key and continue.  yes, it might cause more problems later, but it also might allow more problems to be brought to light in the same run so that they can all be corrected at once, instead of one at a time.

and actually, \PackageError will do the same thing with a more informative message.

Answer (score 13):

you can insert the `end{document}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\foo{}
%\def\foo{quit}  % uncomment for stopping sourcecode reading
\begin{document}

foo
\if\relax\foo\else\par
  I'll stop reading source code \ldots
  \end{document}
\fi

bar
\end{document}
```

If the break is in an included file use:

```
foo
\def\next{}
\if\relax\foo\else\par
  I'll stop reading source code in the included file \ldots
  \def\next{\endinput\end{document}}
\fi
\next

foo in the included file
```

Comment: But don't do this in tex files that are `\include`d, otherwise you may hit a "_Runaway Argument?_" with "_! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile/\@newl@bel_", as in [size-limit for aux, problem w/ hyperref, natbib, include • General • LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4609); `\stop` in those cases seems to work better.

Comment: with a  modification it also possible to quit  the run in an included file!