# What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX

Tags: fun, big-list

I think the questions says it all! :)

By TeX, I mean any derivative of TeX as long as the code is clearly a derivative of TeX, i.e. that it could belong on TeX.SX (and not pure Lua for example).

I'll give two answers myself so you see what I mean.

Comment: Fully-related: [What can't TeX do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27440/5764)

Comment: We tried to elect the Pope. Maybe next time. `:)`

Comment: Related, or somewhat similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/in-what-ways-can-tex-be-used-beyond-document-production

Comment: Related:[Self-replicating (La)TeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91678/15717)

Comment: Related [Are there other “fun” packages like the “coffee stains” package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67656/15717)

Comment: I like how you can ask this sort of thing on tex. You wouldn't get very far on SO with a question like that.

Comment: I like this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133667/showcase-of-beautiful-wine-bottle-labels-made-with-latex-tikz-and-friends

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I think that Steve Hicks controller for a Mars Rover programmed in TeX is a good candidate: [ICFP Contest 2008 - Mars rover in TeX](http://sdh33b.blogspot.dk/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html).

Comment: The writeup for this one is epic, as such tales usually are.

Comment: Sadly the link is not accessible at least from my area :(

Comment: @JouleV The link still works for me, and the article is still worth reading. Maybe the site was temporarily unavailable?

Comment: @MartinHeller .dk is a Denmark domain AFAIK. So it may be not accessible from some countries.

Answer (score 86):

[**Adding coffee stains to your documents**](http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349)

If my documents don't have those stains, my boss / students think(s) I don't drink coffee. If he or they think I am not drinking coffee, they believe I am slacking. Thanks Hanno!

Comment: Great! I need it. I didn't find the package on CTAN - would be nice, if it would be part of TeXLive.

Answer (score 64):

David Carlisle's Christmas 'card' at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xii. 
In fact, here it is: run this through plain TeX:

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

A good collection of [Enjoy TeX pearls diving! at GUST, Polish TeX Users Group](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls)

For more [Pearls of TeX programming at TUGboat ,Volume 26 (2005), No. 3](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84pearls.pdf).

Comment: Could anyone please explain how it works?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen run with `tex xii.tex` and open the `xii.dvi` file.

Comment: @percusse I think Uwe meant how common mortals are supposed to understand David's code. I know: we're not :)

Comment: @Xavier I have a rough summary of the command definitions but not the last big iteration. I'll clean it up and paste it here. But I have to ask David first

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen It's just a typical plain TeX file, the syntax is slightly different to the LaTeX syntax that's more commonly seen here.

Comment: If your French is better than mine... https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups=#!topic/fr.comp.text.tex/tkyaRYXQWnQ

Comment: Ja!!! I don't think so anyway. @David you are a genius.

Comment: `\tracingall` and a few hours later... :D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I guess my French is worse than your's! Will try it using Google Translator.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen have a look [here.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/can-you-explain-how-this-code-works)

Comment: For something similar, and a detailed explanation of the code, see [Can you explain how this code works?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2272/5764)

Comment: First appearance in usenet group `comp.text.tex`, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/Uyp--Qlehfo/DGFBkSjOSMMJ – second version with fixed typo (the one later uploaded to CTAN) in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/Uyp--Qlehfo/bJWS1u7Hn3MJ

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen it is black magic

Comment: you can also use `pdftex`

Answer (score 50):

a basic interpreter written in tex.

see [the tugboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29greene.pdf).

Comment: Does it support Commodore Basic? My Dad could run the program he typed up on the C64 to play Star Fleet battles on it!

Answer (score 49):

Our own [Bruno LeFloch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2707/bruno-le-floch) who wrote a Reversi game which runs in the console:

(Please don't try to reformat the code displayed below unless you really know what you are doing; if you do attempt a reformat, try to compile the resulting code before replacing the code here.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = tex
\long\def\3#1#2#3{}\vsize5cm\hsize4cm\newlinechar`*\def~#1{\catcode`#113~}
~QSU_VWJKLMNO@XY[](|+Z'"z:qj^;/)!,\ ${*13\3}
\def~#1#2{\let#1#2~}~*\cr[\ifnum(\ifcaseO\or|\else]\fiN\number@\advanceX
\expandafterZ\globalY\message~\defj{[0<Q[9>Q[0<J[9>J^|_]|_]|_]|_]}
~+{\count1}+1=9~_#1{@+1 1\countdef#1+1_}_QJVSKWUL,'"$\H!_-1'1"2+44'+55'+45"+54"~^{+NQNJ}
~:#1{#11#12#13#14#15#16#17#18}
~M#1{Y{#1}#1}~\h#1#2{M#2:{ \q#1}&M#2&M{*}}~\q#1#2{&M{(+#1#2  O-O0]}}
~/{Y{Row and column? e.g. E6*}\read_to\MX\j\meaning\M  ;}
~\j#1->#2#3#4;{Q`#2@Q-`@J`#3@J-`0;(VY{Invalid move.}
/]}~;{V0 (jS1z1z0z_S0z1z_S_z1z0z_]}~\_{@,('O-]}
~z#1{{\H0K#1!1{\H1q}(!q]}}~q{@QS@JK[j="(\HZ^'Z\_2]\&q|[j='ZVV($(\H|Z!0]]]]}~\,#1{Q#1:\.}
~\.#1{J#1;[0<V\&[V>WWVUQLJ]]}~\^#1{(#1O0O1O2O2O2O2O1O0]}
~\&{!\^Q\multiply!3@!\^J@V(!9O1O6O1O1O2O6O2O4] }~\Z{M :{&M}&M{*}}
~){'X"X"N'\halign{&## *M{*}
\Z\h1A\h2B\h3C\h4D\h5E\h6F\h7G\h8H\Z}
\vfil\break$1W(W_|0] :\,$0 [0<W[1='QUJL|/];^'\_1][_=WM
{(,Tie| Player [0>,-|0] wins by N[0>,-],].}X\end])})
```

Comment: It is – intentionally, of course – named `reverxii` in reminescence to David Carlisle. Just compare [Peter Flynn’s answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104263/9237).

Comment: I don't know why it's taken me so long to run this through... this is absolutely insane.  Why?  *Why?*

Comment: Side effect, you get a play history printed on the resulting PDF/DVI. ■ (I wonder what algorithm the bot uses. The bot is actually pretty good, almost beat me the time I try.)

Answer (score 45):

I once spent hours learning enough TeX to format my ex-gf's resume  for printing on the computing center laser printer (back when laser printing was magical) and used up most of my monthly laser printing quota printing copies of it -- all under the mistaken belief that she'd see that she was crazy to break up with me.

Not surprisingly, it turned out to be a useless waste of my time (and in retrospect, it was *me* that should have broken up with *her*). Worse, word got around that I was a "TeX expert" and I ended up spending the rest of my computer center operator job helping grad students format their theses

Comment: Sorry, but this not an answer to the spirt of the question.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the {fun} tag

Comment: @Speravir: I'm not sure about the "spirit of the question", but for me, using TeX for making a gf regret breaking up definitely counts.

Comment: Well, I actually once met a nice girl because she needed help formatting her thesis and was told I was a "TeX expert". She's now my wife, and we had our first child 6 months ago :)

Comment: @mbork (and also at Johnny): With an extra-twist I do understand very well, what Johnny’s intention was, and this is actually a nice one :-). But the answers given here by Xavier as the topic starter imply clearly another intention.

Comment: @Xavier: congratulations!

Comment: @mbork For the baby, or for highlighting the incredible value of TeX in a "bizarre" way? :D

Comment: @Xavier: both? :D

Comment: @Xavier Shouldn't there be a word for it... like "TeXpert"?

Comment: Consider deleting this answer

Comment: @MarioS.E. It would be TeXnician as the pronunciation of TeX isn't the one in TeXpert. This is the first question in the TeXbook.

Answer (score 29):

[**Solving a non-linear equation**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67532/iterative-method-to-solve-nonlinear-equations/67763#67763)

Not typesetting the solution (actually, also typesetting the solution of course :)), but more bizarrely implementing the [bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) and [secant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) non-linear solvers in TeX!

Comment: You know, I am at this moment wondering whether there is an easy way to graph some trajectories of a nonlinear system of ODEs in `pgfplots`.  Obviously, my search is ended.  (Oh, this only does *algebraic* equations.  Boooo!)

Comment: @RyanReich: You may have a look at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-ode . Though I must admit that the actual calculation is done by your Postscript printer rather than by TeX.

Answer (score 21):

This one is probably my best:

- [Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284/7417) (please take a look at percusse's comment - pure genius! `:)`)

But there are a few of them scattered around on this site. Here are my picks:

- [Shortest code causing "Emergency stop." error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31517/7417)
- [Stop LaTeX compile with a command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60461/7417)
- [Selectively suppress generation of typeset output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97347/7417)
- [Typesetting the entire Song That Never Ends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95783/7417)
- [Malicious code and/or PDF generation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58051/7417)
- Forcing LaTeX to produce a different PDF on each compile (never reaching a stable output)

... and, as a bonus:

- [How should I convert my beamer slides to PowerPoint according to these odd specifications?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9462/7417)

I really don't see why someone would go back to MS Office after using LaTeX... Now that's weird! `;)`

**EDIT:** and i just remembered this one (Why facebook implemented it? But why recreate it in LaTeX? `;)`):

- [Text upside-down, characters rotated along baseline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28861/7417)

Comment: I am the originator of the "How should I convert my slides to PowerPoint...?" question and if you read it you will note that it was *not* my desire to back to MS Office.  But I'm glad the question has achieved a measure of notoriety.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I know you were forced into it. Nevertheless, it was a weird thing to do IMHO and I'm only happy to advertise it. `:)`

Comment: and years later, I can add that I use beamer, but some of my users want to modify the slides and only know word.  yikes.  so I have to maintain both.

Answer (score 21):

**[Calculating π with TeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/misc/pi.tex)**

Gen­er­ates π, us­ing the for­mula

```
pi=16*arc­tan(1/5)-4*arc­tan(1/239)
```

and leaves the re­sult in an ar­ray `\xr`, print­ing what it’s cal­cu­lated as it goes along.

Answer (score 20):

Well, as made famous by a [question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/7880) I have used LaTeX to make to make props for a Call of Cthulhu game. [I also posted the finished product on my blog.](https://canageek.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/summon-invisible-servant/)

Then later on I used the same technique to make my teaching assistant's life [a bit more interesting](https://canageek.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/the-journal-entry-of-cthulhu/)

Answer (score 19):

**Implementing the bisection method** (and other numerical methods) in TikZ,
for exposition purposes.

**EDIT**: Great thanks to percusse for helping me improve my `\ifg` command.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% 'if #1 greater than #2 then #3 else #4' construct (compatible with pgfmath)
\newcommand{\ifg}[4]{
    \pgfmathparse{(#1)>(#2)?int(1):int(0)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1relax%
        #3%
    \else%
        #4%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\extendxaxis}{.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\extendyaxis}{.3}
    \colorlet{acolor}{red}
    \colorlet{bcolor}{OliveGreen}
    \colorlet{ccolor}{orange}
    \colorlet{fcolor}{blue}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{\pgfmathparse{.5*(exp(-#1)-#1)}} % continuous function
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ao}{.2}   % lower-bound of initial bracket
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bo}{1}    % upper-bound of initial bracket
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\co}{0}    % midpoint of inital bracket (initialised at 0)
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{3}        % number of iterations

    \ifx\ao\bo % check that \ao and \bo are distinct 
        \node[red] (0,0) {Bisection impossible: singleton initial bracket.};
    \else%
        \ifg{\ao}{\bo}{ % if \ao > \bo, swop them
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\bo}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\bo}{\ao}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ao}{\temp}
        }{}
        % code in here
        \ifg{{f(\ao)*f(\bo)}}{0}{%
            \node[red] (0,0) {Bisection impossible: no root in initial bracket.};
        }{%
            \onslide<1->{%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{\ao-.5*\extendxaxis*(\bo-\ao)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{\bo+.5*\extendxaxis*(\bo-\ao)}
                \draw[->] (\xmin,0) node[left] {$0$} --
                    (\xmax,0) node[right] {$x$};
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{min(f(\ao),f(\bo))-.5*\extendyaxis*abs(f(\bo)-f(\ao))}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{max(f(\ao),f(\bo))+.5*\extendyaxis*abs(f(\bo)-f(\ao))}
                \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[left] {$f(x)$};
                \draw[fcolor] plot[domain=\xmin:\xmax] (\x,{f(\x)});
            }
            \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \k in {1,2,...,\n}{%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{\k}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\co}{0.5*(\ao+\bo)}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\k-1}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fromslide}{3*(\k-1)+2}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\toslide}{\fromslide+2}
                \onslide<\fromslide-\toslide>{
                    \draw[thick,acolor] (\ao,.1ex) --
                        (\ao,-.1ex) node[below] {$a_{\j}$}; % a0
                    \draw[thick,bcolor] (\bo,.1ex) --
                        (\bo,-.1ex) node[below] {$b_{\j}$}; % b0
                }
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fromslide}{\fromslide+1}
                \onslide<\fromslide-\toslide>{%
                    \draw[thick,ccolor] (\co,.1ex) --
                        (\co,-.1ex) node[below] {$c_{\j}$};     
                }
                \onslide<\toslide>{%
                    \coordinate (a0) at (\ao,{f(\ao)});     
                    \draw[dashed,thin,red]  (a0 |- \xmin,0) -- (a0)
                        -- (a0 -| \xmin,0) node[left] {$f(a_{\j})$};% dashed lines
                    \draw[fill,red] (a0) circle (.05ex);            
                    \coordinate (c0) at (\co,{f(\co)}); 
                    \draw[dashed,thin,orange]   (c0 |- \xmin,0) -- (c0)
                        -- (c0 -| \xmin,0) node[left] {$f(c_{\j})$};% dashed lines      
                    \draw[fill,orange] (c0) circle (.05ex);                                 
                }
                \ifg{f(\ao)*f(\co)}{0}{ % bisection iteration
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ao}{\co}
                }{%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bo}{\co}
                }
                \ifx\n\k%
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\toslide}{\toslide+1}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\j+1}
                    \onslide<\toslide>{%
                        \draw[thick,acolor] (\ao,.1ex) --
                            (\ao,-.1ex) node[below] {$a_{\j}$}; % a0 
                        \draw[thick,bcolor] (\bo,.1ex) --
                            (\bo,-.1ex) node[below] {$b_{\j}$}; % b0 
                    }
                \fi                     
            }
        }
    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything special to compile your code? It hangs with ` File ended while scanning use of \next.` :(

Comment: Weird. Works great on my machine, but copying and pasting it on the site introduces an error somewhere... I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Xavier Remove the white-space in front of `\end{frame}` and it works. The manual states for using `fragile`: “In this case, […] the `\end{frame}` must be alone on a single line.”

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! If TeX starts to be picky about spaces, I am lost :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks. Feel free to edit my answer accordingly. I've tried your improvement but I get an error...

Comment: @percusse I've tried `\newcommand{\ifg}[4]{%
 \pgfmathparse{#1>#2?int(1):int(0)}\ifnum\pgfmathresult1%
        #3%
    \else%
        #4%
    \fi%
}` but I get an error: `Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read again> \begingroup }{}`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @percusse If I define `\newcommand{\ifg}[4]{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1>#2?int(1):int(0)}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax%
        #3%
    \else%
        #4%
    \fi%
}`, my code returns errors. My original definition of `\ifg` and your proposed simplification must not be equivalent, somehow. I'm lost.

Comment: @percusse I couldn't figure it out. Works like a charm now. Great thanks for that!

Comment: @Jubobs My pleasure. Let's clean up the comments to reduce the our noise :)

Answer (score 16):

**[Providing an excuse for slacking off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122116/8057)**

Just let (La)TeX burn some CPU cycles while you are relaxing.

Comment: The #1 programmers excuse for legitimately slacking off: http://xkcd.com/303/

Answer (score 15):

Enrico “[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427)” Gregorio posted this into our TeX.sx chat:

1. Let me name it `xcix.tex`, because it’s in the manner of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)’s `xii.tex`, cf. [Peter Flynn’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104263/)

   ```
   \let~\catcode~`x13~`q~`x~`z~`q~`H~`q~`B~`H~`j0~`jA009
   jlet~jlet~Hjpar ~Bjmscount~~jdef~x{q bottlez of beer}
   ~jw{x on the wall}~jt{jadvanceAB-1ATake one down Aand
   pass it around,H}B99~ji{jifnumB}~q{ji=0Nojelsejnumber
   Bjfi}~z{ji>1sjfiA }jloop jifnumB>0 jw, x,Hjtjw.jvskip
   8ptplus1ptjrepeat Time to buy some more beerjdotsjend
   ```

   ([source link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=13496147))
2. The same as LaTeX3 version

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xparse}

   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}

   \ExplSyntaxOn
   % user level command
   \NewDocumentCommand{\beers} { O{99} }
    {
     \manual_beers_sing:n { #1 }
    }
   % variables
   \int_new:N \l_manual_beers_count_int
   % functions
   \cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_beers_sing:n #1
    {
     \int_set:Nn \l_manual_beers_count_int { #1 }
     \prg_replicate:nn { \l_manual_beers_count_int }
      {
       \manual_beers_print:
       \int_decr:N \l_manual_beers_count_int
      }
     Time ~ to ~ buy ~ some ~ more ~ beer ~ \dots
    }
   \cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_beers_print:
    {
     \manual_beer_text:nn { ~ on ~ the ~ wall }{ 0 }, ~
     \manual_beer_text:nn { } { 0 }, \\
     Take ~ one ~ down ~ and ~ pass ~ it ~ around, \\
     \manual_beer_text:nn { ~ on ~ the ~ wall } { -1 }.\par
    }
   \cs_new:Npn \manual_beer_text:nn #1 #2
    {
     \int_case:nnF { \l_manual_beers_count_int + #2 }
      {
       { 0 } { No ~ bottle ~ of ~ beer }
       { 1 } { 1 ~ bottle ~ of ~ beer }
      }
      {
       \int_to_arabic:n { \l_manual_beers_count_int + #2 } ~ bottles ~ of ~ beer
      }
     #1
    }
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \begin{document}
   \beers
   \end{document}
   ```

   ([source link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=13496309), [small correction](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=13496417); *the code as seen above is, though, in this version, as it will appear in a manual by Enrico, which is in the moment, this code was posted, in process of writing*)

This was influenced by me, because I had posted these two links:

- [99 Bottles of Beer | Language TeX/LaTeX](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-tex-latex-445.html) *(for compilation read comment of Kiyoshi Akima below that code)*
- [99 Bottles of Beer | Language LaTeX2e](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-latex2e-2365.html) loading `fmtcount` and `tikz`
  *(which has a link to an older version [99 Bottles of Beer | Language LaTeX2e](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-latex2e-1842.html) working with `memoir` and loading only `ifthen`)*

Comment: May I ask what is `\mscount`? I surmise it is like `\newcount`, but cannot find it anywhere. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 13):

[**Implementing a Turing machine simulator**](http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_%28LaTeX%29)
(TeX is Turing complete)

Hail to the busy beaver!

Comment: Link is broken (domain for sale).

Answer (score 13):

At this stage, having seen a lot of bizarre things done with LaTeX by *users* :-) I should probably add the `bookshelf` package I posted to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookshelf/) recently.

This takes a BiBTeX file (eg your thesis) and turns it into an image of a bookshelf so you can use it as a background during video calls; in my case to cover up the fact that my bookshelves were hideously untidy :-)

[image]

Comment: Wow... how did you even think of this?

Comment: Some years ago I was playing with the idea of formatting actual book spines in LaTeX (starting with the TeXbook, of course) to make a virtual bookshelf. It's basically a \rotatebox of the text inside a \colorbox,. Then the first lockdown came along and I saw that instead of trying to retypeset the actual appearance, you could just pick a size and shape and a font using the random package, and take the data from any BiBTeX file.

Answer (score 2):

**[The avremu package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/avremu/README)**

…emulates an 8-bit CPU (ATmega8).

Comment: From the manual: “This picture (250x250) took 44 hours to render. ”. ;-)