# TeX - LaTeX in pop culture

Tags: fun

I'm doing a research on free-software references in movies, TV series, etc.

Things like: "in Dr. House they use KDE as DE" or "Sheldon from the The Big Bang Theory uses Ubuntu." And the like.

I'd love to include some TeX/LaTeX facts, but I've not managed to find any reference. Can you help me?

Only restriction is that the movie/TV series etc. must be English.

I didn't know where to put this question so went for fun. Hope you don't mind this sort of questions, please forgive me if this is not allowed.

Comment: I believe that there is no such movies except the related with TeX developments, if they exists.

Comment: @Sigur This was the same first comment I received in the forum of a very famous free software project which is now the fifth most referenced in my list :)

Comment: I recall a film actually showing LaTeX code on screen, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @Werner that would be good too, even if LaTeX was not actually named but it was clearly LaTeX it is ok

Comment: @f.boc, well, let's wait for the experts. Now I'm curious to see some movies too.

Comment: Some sort of intelligent evil robot plane movie.

Comment: this is actually a difficult research job because both "tex" and "latex" have other and more popular meanings...

Comment: In the bad film [Stealth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382992/) some LaTeX code appears for some seconds (not sure if it's LaTeX or Plain).

Comment: @Werner perhaps you mean the film "Stealth" that I just mentioned in a comment? Once I saw the whole film just to see the code appear. It appeared all right, but seeing the movie just for that was a total waste of time.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'll take a look and see if I can find it

Comment: I believe that is easier to find a movie with somebody using `beamer` on a presentation.

Comment: Also, not directly TeX, but its creator: [`xkcd: Donald Knuth`](http://xkcd.com/163/) and [`1337: Part 2`](http://xkcd.com/342/), and [`Log Scale`](https://xkcd.com/1162/) (when you hover the mouse over the drawing), and [`Applied math`](http://xkcd.com/816/).

Comment: A reference to TeX won't be a popular one :)

Comment: [The slides for UK’s infamous Tempora project were done in LaTeX/beamer and later leaked to the press, who published at least one screenshot](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2013/jun/21/gchq-mastering-the-internet).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina if you like you can cut the image from the answer and put into an answer

Comment: try this google query: 'latex in popular culture' ---  the second entry refers to this thread. the first entry refers to wikipedia (thanks that i was alone in the office when opening it). that's precision and recall of google :-))

Comment: @mnemonic we're gonna make it popular :)

Answer (score 53):

The movie [Stealth (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382992/) has the following storyline summary:

> In the near future, the Navy develops a fighter jet piloted by an artificial intelligence computer. The jet is placed on an aircraft carrier in the Pacific to learn combat manuevers from the human pilots aboard. But when the computer develops a mind of its own, it's the humans who are charged with stopping it before it incites a war...

The artificial intelligence computer (or AI) was programmed by the character Dr Keith Orbit (played by [Richard Roxburgh](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0746896/)). [Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382992/trivia) for this movie includes a [reference to LaTeX](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382992/trivia?item=tr0674116):

> When Keith Orbit is looking at the code for the AI, we can see that the code is written in LaTeX, which is a language for typesetting mathematics much as HTML is used on the Internet for typesetting web pages.

Here's a screen grab from [the movie](http://youtu.be/h42b_soNFfw) (1:09:06):

[image]

Comment: I wonder whether this source would be traceable to a publicly available document...

Comment: I would say that if it is an AI, it surely should not be programmed in TeX, but [iTeX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKaI78K_rgA) (bell ringing here), but alas, it is not XML...

Comment: @JLDiaz Well, Steve Hicks wrote a [Mars Rover controller in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104258/10102), so why not a stealth fighter? :D

Comment: Has anyone figured out what is being sown on screen, or is there not enough of it to compile a reasonable facsimile?

Comment: My code isn't exactly clean as a whistle, but wow, that's messy...

Answer (score 32):

The XKCD comic [`File Extensions`](http://xkcd.com/1301/) references TeX directly:

[image: I have never been lied to by data in a .txt file which has been hand-aligned.]

Answer (score 30):

Not directly related to TeX, but to its creator (so it's worth mentioning it); there are some references to Donald Knuth in some of xkcd's comics:

[`Donald Knuth`](http://xkcd.com/163/)

[`1337: Part 2`](http://xkcd.com/342/)

[`Log Scale`](http://xkcd.com/1162/) (hover the mouse over the drawing)

[`Applied math`](http://xkcd.com/816/)

Comment: To read the alt-text in a iPad (which does not support hovering), prepend `m.` to the url of the xkcd comic. Eg, http://m.xkcd.com/1162/

Answer (score 25):

Maybe can help:

> "So you can create these tables?" she asked him. "In a form suitable
>    for a TEX file?" TEX, pronounced like "Tech," is a computer program
>    that's used for typesetting technical papers and books. "No," said
>    Turner. "I don't do TEX. I do Troff (a comparable program). I guess
>    I'll have to learn it, though. It's an invention of the devil."
>
> Lemonick, M. D., *The Light at the Edge of the Universe* (1993)

(cited in David Salomon, *The Advanced TeXbook* (1995))

Comment: +1 for 'invention of the devil' `:)` Does it mean Knuth is the devil?

Answer (score 23):

I've seen this one from Something of that Ilk pop up a few times:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150526124611/http://www.somethingofthatilk.com/index.php?id=135

It seems that the official site of the comic has been shut down, hence the link to archive.org.

[image]

Comment: I love that one ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, that site seems to've closed down and is now a squatter. Link to the Wayback Machine Archive?

Answer (score 22):

I once saved the following picture from a Facebook group called "Trust Me I'm an Engineer". Pretty sure those are LaTeX codes ;-)

Here is the [link to the "source"](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151195871418360&set=pb.290539813359.-2207520000.1372117122.&type=3&theater)

[image]

---

Also, [PHD Comics](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics.php) published two episodes where LaTeX was referred to:

- [Summer To Do](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1521) (at the bottom)
- [OMG! ROTFL!!](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1178) (at the middle)

Answer (score 21):

A reference to the creator of TeX - DEK: [Doctor Fun](http://www.ibiblio.org/Dave/drfun.html) produced cartoons over a "520 week" period (spanning around 10 years). This one is from [February 10th, 2000](http://www.ibiblio.org/Dave/Dr-Fun/df200002/df20000210.jpg):

[image]

This alleged book, *Donald Knuth's Big Dummies Guide to Visual Basic*, is purely fictional.

Answer (score 12):

The central character of R.A. MacAvoy’s wonderful fantasy novel, *Tea with the Black Dragon* settles down to read Dr. Donald Knuth’s *The Art of Computer Programming* with, “a contented sigh”.