# Cleaner Code for a Table design

Tags: tables, fun

in this question  [Showcase of beautiful wine bottle labels made with LaTeX/TikZ and friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133667/showcase-of-beautiful-wine-bottle-labels-made-with-latex-tikz-and-friends) I asked for wine bottle labels.
Here is my own attempt. I still have to play with fonts.

[image]

I'm quite happy with the design but not with the code. It is based on a table layout in a `tcolorbox` (for the background picture). 
So my question is: is it possible to achieve a design like my label with "cleaner code"? Maybe there is a cleaner solution without using tables?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{PTSansCaption} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\bls}
\setlength{\bls}{\baselineskip-\doublerulesep}


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\sodef\an{}{.4em}{1em plus1em}{2em plus.1em minus.1em}


\tcbset{
bgtable/.style={
freelance,
frame code={\draw[] (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east);}
center title,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
watermark graphics=#1,
watermark stretch=1.00,
watermark opacity=0.3,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
nobeforeafter}
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[
  bgtable=papiro.png,
  tabularx*={}{C{20mm} | L{30mm} L{10mm} @{}C{1mm} @{}L{18mm} @{}C{1mm} @{}| L{20mm}},
  watermark stretch=1.00,
  width=10.8cm,
  watermark opacity=0.8,
  top=.51cm,
  bottom=.31cm,
]
%erste Linie über Tabelle
   & \multicolumn{6}{c}{}  \\[-2\bls] \cline{2-6}

%erste Zeile
     \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[width=.9cm]{path2456.png}~~\,}} &
     \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\raisebox{-.7pt}{\scshape\sffamily \bfseries \so{MET 8$\cdot$\&$\cdot$30}}} & 
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{7}{*}{\begin{turn}{90}\ttfamily  herb\end{turn}}} \\
     \cline{2-6}

%%zweite Zeile
   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{\tiny
       \scshape \RaggedRight Honig,  Wasser, Äpfel, Hefe, 
       und vor allem Zeit braucht man, um selbstgemachten Met verschenken
       zu können. Du hälst gerade ein solches Geschenk in der Hand. \newline Wenn es Dir
      schmeckt, lass es mich wissen.}} 
       }  
       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}    
       &\\
%
%%dritte Zeile
   &    
     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny Charge:} 
     &    
     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tiny Flaschennummer:}    
     &
     &\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} 

%%vierte Zeile
   & 
     & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\ttfamily 09\,/\,13} 
     & 
     & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\ttfamily 3\,/\,15} 
     &
     &\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%leere ``Zeile``
     \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  \\[-\bls] \cline{3-5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%fünfte Zeile
   &
     & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{{\tiny gebraut von:} \ttfamily Schmendrich}      
     & \\
     \cline{3-5} 
   & \multicolumn{5}{r|}{\miniscule \sffamily natürlich mit Schwefel} 
   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{}\\ \cline{2-6}

\end{tcolorbox}



\end{document}
```

Comment: why is every entry in a `\multicolumn` ? It means `tabularx` and the original table specification aren't used at all???

Comment: I got the basic frame of that table from excel2latex. It is for the vertical lines. In some places I wanted the lines only for a cell but not for the whole row. Is there another way to achieve that without using multicolumn?

Comment: sorry I'm an idiot:-) I'll delete my comments.

Comment: Are you loading `booktabs` just for its spacing? I notice you are still using `\cline`.

Comment: Yes, I used it just for spacing. But if there is a better way: please show it. That is what i asked for.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to translate the design to tikz nodes? Well, admittedly I always use tikz even if it is not the more appropriate tool, but in this case I think it fits well. And the question has tag `fun`! :-)

Comment: @JLDiaz: Maybe you are right and it is easier to translate it to tikz nodes. But I'm not very familiar with it. Would like to see a tikz solution.