# Need Recommendation for creating honey label in LaTeX

Tags: labels

I am an MS student in computer science and engineering at the University of Dhaka, Bangladesh. Alongside my studies, I have a business of honey. I want to stand my honey as a brand. I also decided my brand name "vaijan" means brother. For introducing my honey as a brand I need a simple but gorgeous honey label.

I like LaTeX typesetting and try to create all things using LaTeX. I read an article about the label in LaTeX(https://blog.worldlabel.com/2010/label-card-printing-resources-with-tex-and-latex.html).

But I am not sure where I should start. Please recommend me a starting point.

My current honey pot with honey.

[image: honey label]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133667/showcase-of-beautiful-wine-bottle-labels-made-with-latex-tikz-and-friends .

Comment: Check out the ‘Wedding of the Bugs TV’ font at http://abfonts.freehostia.com/index.htm ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some honey combs. This is a community wiki that others can add ornaments or honey bees. One may clip the honey comb grid in the end.
The honey combs look better with a bit thicker lines and instead of black in a dark honey color:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\definecolor{honey1}{RGB}{244,255,89}
\definecolor{honey2}{RGB}{248,195,12}
\definecolor{darkhoney}{HTML}{E79100}
\newcounter{hexi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/hexi/.style={code={\stepcounter{hexi}
\node[draw=darkhoney,very thick,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum width=2cm,
path picture={
\shade[inner color=honey1,outer color=honey2]
(0.4,0.2) circle[radius=1.4cm];}]
(hexi-\number\value{hexi}) {};
}}]
 %\clip (0,1) rectangle (9.8,6.5);
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,6} {
 foreach \Y in {1,...,4} { 
 \ifodd\X 
  ({\X*(1+cos(60))},{\Y*(2*sin(60))})
 \else
  ({\X*(1+cos(60))},{\Y*(2*sin(60))-sin(60)})
 \fi pic{hexi}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]