# How to make old school vintage label?

Tags: pgfornament

[image]

I want to make a honey label like this using holden font. But I can't start. Can you guys make a template for this?

Comment: have a look --Showcase of beautiful wine bottle labels made with LaTeX/TikZ and friends-----https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133667/showcase-of-beautiful-wine-bottle-labels-made-with-latex-tikz-and-friends?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29805/197451

Comment: @jsbibra The last link is about the pstricks version  here the tag indicates "pgfornament". I made this package so I can say hat the symbols are the same. I translate the ps version into a pgf version

Comment: We (or I ) can do this but perhaps you can try to do a minimal example...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a do-it-for-me question that does not show effort from the asker.

Answer (score 6):

You need to look at the documentation !

An example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-handout} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzrput}     

\begin{document}  
\null\vspace{5cm}  


  \begin{center}
  \rput[r](-3pt,3pt){\pgfornament[scale=.5]{72}}
  {\huge Motifs d'ornements}%
  \rput[l](3pt,3pt){\pgfornament[scale=.5]{73}}\\
  \rput(0,0){\pgfornament[scale=.5]{85}}
  \end{center} 


\begin{center}
\rput[r](-2pt,6pt){\pgfornament[color=black,height=1cm]{21}}
{\Large Texte}%   
\rput[l](2pt,6pt){\pgfornament[color=black,height=1cm]{23}} 
\end{center}   
 \end{document}
```

If you have difficulties, ask a new question !
You can change the class you can add pictures ... but we need to know if you work with patrick's, tikz or something else ...

[image]